# preg_match need for accept only positive floating point number

Tags: php, regex, numbers, preg-match

preg_match need for accept only positive floating point numbers .
Example: 1.5 or 10 and not for -1.5 or -10 values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your current code failing?

Comment: i want to accept 0 and positive floating point numbers. EG: i need 0.1 or 0 or 10 like this.

Comment: Yes, I got that. What I politely asking was: What did you try before posting here? This is very basic stuff, we'll be happy to debug your code if it's failing but StackOverflow isn't a regex generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(preg_match("/^\d+(?:\.\d+)?$/", $number)){
    // do some process
}
```

Here `(\.\d+)?` is checking for optional decimal point with digits!

`?:` is used to avoid capturing the group.